# "Textbook" example of UART doesn't work on stm32f756zg. HAL_UART_Transmit() returns HAL_BUSY

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, nucleo

I want to send a message through uart5 of my nucleo board. I configured UART5 appropriately as per https://wiki.st.com/stm32mcu/wiki/Getting_started_with_UART .

Here is main():

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  unsigned char s[]="message";

  while (1)
  { 
      if(HAL_UART_Transmit(UART5,s,6,HAL_MAX_DELAY)==HAL_BUSY)
      {
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_7,1);
      }
  }
}
```

This effectively lights up the Blue Led on the board if the HAL_UART_Transmit() returns HAL_BUSY. The led lights up. If I change HAL_BUSY to HAL_OK in the above code and reupload the program, then the blue led never lights up.

EDIT:
I only added the code inside the while loop (plus `s` definition), the rest of the project is generated code, CMSIS headers, HAL source files. If I take the added code and put it before the while loop, it doesn't solve the problem.

My question is how to send anything with UART on any stm32f7 board? This particular board is stm32f756zg.

I rebuildt the project several times just to be sure I did everything right. I did it in stm32CubeIDE under both windows and linux.

Comment: OK, but you don't ask a question which needs an answer. Please ask a question. On what board is that? Is the LED active low or high? There are code missing, that can't compile to a binary so nobody can try that code on any hardware.

Comment: I'll take a stab:  Perhaps because you are continuously (while 1) transmitting "message" as fast as possible, the poor UART always considers itself busy because it's continuously transmitting the "message" message?  And since it's continuously busy, busy, busy, GPOI_Pin_7 is always set to '1'.  Of course, if you invert the HAL_BUSY logic, you don't in any way make the UART less busy, because the UART is still transmitting out the "message" message as fast, and as often, as it can. message message message message message message message message message message message message message

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen That API function waits forever if told for the transmit to be complete. And it is told to wait about 4 gigaseconds. Also, the code is wired such that even if the API returns even once with busy, the LED is lit forever as there is no code to turn the LED off.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The main problem is that nothing comes through the pins and the function never ever returns HAL_OK indicating normal operation. I looked at the source of HAL_UART_Transmit() and the problem is that  huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_TX is always true. Maybe I miss some configuration step.

Comment: Well that does not look like it came out of CubeMX and works. What is "UART5"? Either that's incorrect, or they have changed UART handle names within two weeks, or F756 firmware HAL is different from all other I've ever seen. Even the example disagrees with your code. Did you get errors or warnings compiling it?

Comment: what did st say when you asked?

Comment: I tried UART5 and UART5_BASE and another 10 versions and different UARTs. Yes it is wierd because you have USART1 USART2 but UART4 UART5 UART6. The code i have given doesn't exactly correspond to the link any more because i kept altering  it to make it to debug it. Anyway @old_timer is right st.com is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: Break before the transmit attempt then view and review the UART5 register settings in the IDE to make sure they're correct.  Or download the STM32CubeF7 example software package and try the UART example in there.